# Mentioning user username in comments (@mention) - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app, if a user mentions another username in a comment by using the @ character, such as @max i'm trying to add autocomplete to suggest a list of users and then automatically create a link_to (username, user_path(user)

This is what I have in my comment partial:

```
<%= form_for [commentable, Comment.new] do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :commentable_type, commentable.class.to_s %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :commentable_id, commentable.id %>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to use this gem: https://github.com/ichord/jquery-atwho-rails

It says to bind the text area with

```
data = ['tom','john'];
$('textarea').atwho({at:"@", 'data':data});
```

**Where do I actually put this? Can I do something like data = User.all? Should I just be using a regular expression to do this?**

Comment: Have you tried using `data = User.all`? It would be faster to try than to ask.

Comment: Yup, right under the form in my comment partial, the page load fine, but nothing happens when I enter @someusername:  <script>

data = User.all ;
$('textarea').atwho({at:"@", 'data':data});

</script>

Comment: You cannot just enter ruby code into JavaScript files.

Comment: I kinda figured, how do I connect the two?

Comment: Something that small you can put into your view. IE `<script>data = <%= User.all %> ... </script>

Comment: That does not work, It still thinks everything inside of the script tags is JavaScript

Comment: Ruby would convert it before it gets sent to the client.

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48716/discussion-between-justin-wood-and-katie-heidmann)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<script> 
  data = <%= raw User.pluck(:username).compact.to_json %>;
  $('textarea').atwho({at:"@", 'data':data}); 
</script>
```

You might want to move the loading of the usernames into the controller or a helper method. The whole sniplet might belong into an view partial to keep things organized. And it might not be the best idea to load all usernames into the view when there are too many users in the database.

Answer (score 4):

I think the reason that `data = User.all` isn't working is because `User.all` will return an array of `User` objects. What you want to do is retrieve those `User` object `usernames` (or whatever you want the autocomplete to use, and store that in `data` instead.

You might try something like

```
@usernames = User.pluck(:username)
```

to get all the usernames. Then, in your partial:

```
data = <% @usernames &>
$('textarea').atwho({at:"@", 'data':data});
```

This is assuming of course that your partial is an `.erb` file where you can embed ruby code.